# Install window service within wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, service, window

I have two projects wpf and window service. I have created setup for wpf project. I want to install window service withing wpf project setup i.e once user install wpf project, window service will install automatically. Is it possible.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Your installer should install both WPF application and windows service.

Comment: You could use either use InstallUtil.exe or InstallShield to install a Windows Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services

Comment: As I understand InstallUtil.exe is command line utility for installing window service and InstallShield is used for making installer. But I want to install window service within my wpf project. Something like adding InstallUtil.exe in prerequisite, but don't know how to add.

Comment: Hello @Tarlok, did you find the answer to your question? if yes, then please share as I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Tarlok Please share the solution if you found one.